# How to return the corresponding string in chisel?

Tags: scala, chisel

I want to return the name of the corresponding uop according to the ordinal number of the uop.

I have tried various methods without success. I feel that there is a problem with the type usage of chisel and scala.

After I've relearned scala and chisel's use of variables, I'm still not quite sure what to do.

```
 object GetUopcStr
    {
      def apply(uopc: UInt) = {
        val uopStr = VecInit("uopNOP","uopLD","uopSTA","uopSTD")
        uopStr(uopc)
      }
    }


 object GetUopcStr
    {
      def apply(uopc: UInt) = {
        val uopStr = Seq("uopNOP","uopLD","uopSTA","uopSTD")
        val multiVec = VecInit(for(string <- uopStr) yield string)
        // or
        // val multiVec = VecInit(strings)
        multiVec(uopc)
      }
    }




object GetUopcStr
    {
      def apply(uopc: UInt) = {
        val uopStr = Seq("uopNOP","uopLD","uopSTA","uopSTD")
        uopStr(uopc)
      }
    }
```

Both methods above have errors. I guess the above is a function in scala syntax. I'm supposed to generate the circuit inside. So in the end it should be chisel's Vec type.

Comment: Could you show us the bigger picture of what you are trying to do with the string? There is probably some confusion of Scala and Hardware types, but the solution to your questions depends on what context you are trying to use these functions in.

Answer (score 0):

This [scastie example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MjNNiLW3QG6NZfKNtl7kSw) is a working example of what I think you are trying to do. It's important to understand that chisel is a meta-language that describes how to construct a circuit. Your examples above seem to be based on a software viewpoint. Chisel modules have wires going in and wires going out with the modules doing hardware manipulations to accomplish the module's task. They are similar to software methods but quite different in use. I'd recommend reviewing the [chisel bootcamp](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-bootcamp)